# JQuery UI scale effect not working with flash object

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-ui

Ok, I have a really simple problem. I have a div with a flash object in it. That div is going to pop up in a modal triggered when a user clicks a thumbnail of the flash presentation. The problem occurs when I try to use the scale effect to scale in or out, it errors out. What is going on?? Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="modal"><object id="presentation" width="720" height="576" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" align="middle">
     <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
     <param name="movie" value=" video.swf" />
     <param name="quality" value="high" />
     <param name="bgcolor" value="#c0c0c0" />
     <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
     <embed src=" video.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#c0c0c0" width="720" height="576" name="presentation" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" allowFullScreen="true" /></object></div>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#modal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 750,
        height: 635,
        modal: true,
        show: "scale",
        hide: "fade"
    });
    $("#video a").click(function () {
        $("#modal").dialog('open');
        return false;
    })
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya I have had this problem too. Its something to do with flash and that effect not playing nicely.

I have been able to find a work around though. Take out the  HTML and use the [SWFObject plugin](http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/) to embed the flash file after you have told the dialog to open. The code would look like this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#modal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 750,
        height: 635,
        modal: true,
        show: "scale",
        hide: "fade",
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $("#modal").empty();
        }
    });
    $("#video a").click(function () {
        $("#modal").dialog('open');
        $("#modal").flash({
            swf: 'video.swf',
            width: 720,
            height: 526
        });
        return false;
    })
});
```

Hope this helps!